# R detect pattern like seasonality

Tags: r, time-series

I'm looking for a packages to detect pattern for example seasonality. I have a dataframe with two columns: Day(Date) and Visits.

And when I plot the data I see that the visits on the website are in summer month higher than in the other months. And this pattern I can see over 10 years.

The problem is that I want to analyse the seasonality with data from hundreds of websites.

Please provide me with an example to detect this pattern on the timeseries?

Comment: Maybe see the top answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57705/identify-seasonality-in-time-series-data

Comment: Check out the stl() function.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/view=TimeSeries

Comment: Thanks for the usefull answers! My problem actually is that I got two variables Date and Visits. But when I use TS then I only need one column and then I get the answer "y should be a univariate time series"? Someone know this issue? I get the issue when I use: x <- ts(days, frequency=365/7)
fit <- tbats(x)
seasonal <- !is.null(fit$seasonal)

Comment: @user860480, most time series analysis requires a univariate time series where each value covers one period (day, year, etc). That's a big reason I like `prophet` and used it in my answer. It's designed for time series data like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook released the `prophet` package to simplify time series analysis. There are tons of other ways to look for seasonality, but I think `prophet` is the easiest to use without tweaking. I recommend reading Facebook's [documentation](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#r-api).

First let's create a sample of your data.

```
library(tidyverse)
website <-
  tibble(date = seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = "day"),
         visits = round(rnorm(732, mean = 327, sd = 100)))
```

Let's increase the website traffic during the summer.

```
library(lubridate)
website <-
  mutate(website, ifelse(month(date) %in% c(6, 7, 8), visits + 10, visits))
```

Now for the `prophet` calculations!

```
library(prophet)
website <- website %>% 
  rename(ds = date, y = visits)
m <- prophet(website)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
```

Visualize the results.

```
plot(m, forecast)
```

[image]

It definitely looks like there's more traffic in the summer but it's hard to be certain. Fortunately, `prophet` has a function to examine daily and weekly seasonality.

```
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)
```

[image]

See that increase in the "yearly" chart? You definitely have more website traffic in the summer than you do in the rest of the year!

## Update

In response to comments, here's a quick and easy way to test for any monthly seasonality within each website. It applies an `anova` test to each group. This example gives website B a seasonal effect, which you can see in the `statistic` and `p.value` columns.

First create the demo data...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

website <-
  tibble(
    site = c(rep("A", 732), rep("B", 732), rep("C", 732)),
    date = rep(seq(
      as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = "day"
    ), 3),
    visits = rep(round(rnorm(
      732, mean = 327, sd = 100
    )), 3)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(month = month(date))

website <-
  mutate(website, visits = ifelse(month %in% c(6,7,8) &
                           site == "B", visits + 1000, visits))
```

Now use the wonders of the `tidyverse` to run the test across each group...

```
website %>% 
  split(.$site) %>% 
  map(~ tidy(aov(visits ~ month, data = .)))

#$A
#       term  df       sumsq    meansq statistic   p.value
#1     month   1    3645.896  3645.896 0.3529069 0.5526563
#2 Residuals 730 7541662.108 10331.044        NA        NA

#$B
#       term  df     sumsq    meansq statistic    p.value
#1     month   1   1086355 1086355.5  5.426011 0.02011086
#2 Residuals 730 146155160  200212.5        NA         NA

#$C
#       term  df       sumsq    meansq statistic   p.value
#1     month   1    3645.896  3645.896 0.3529069 0.5526563
#2 Residuals 730 7541662.108 10331.044        NA        NA
```

Note that this is not the ideal method for performing time series analysis, but it answers the specific question that you're asking.

Comment: Thats an awesome answer thanks!! It is a very interesting package! :) Is there a possibilty to get an value for the seasonality of an website? So this website has a seasonality and the other one not? In the interesting yearly plot: Is that the plott-solution over the three years wirhout the forecast (2015-2017)? I ask because there is a 01 in the lettering.

Comment: Are you looking to answer the question "Which of these websites have more traffic in the summer than the rest of the year?" Because there's a very simple approach that I can show you there. Also, you said you only have two columns in your data, so how do you know which datapoint is referring to which website? Happy to edit my answer once you give me more information. And remember to select this answer using the checkbox under the score if it's your favorite.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the answer "Which of these websites have more traffic in SOME months, for example in the summer or in December?" This is very simple to answer this question with a value to decide yes or no? I've got three columns: website, date and visits. But because of the ts-form from the package forecast I use only the columns date and visit. I'm vers excited about your answer! And if your solution I works, I use the checkbox to select your answer!

Comment: In the interesting yearly plot: Is that the plott-solution over the three years (summary from three years) wirhout the forecast (2015-2017)? I ask because there is a 01 in the letterin. And is there a possibilty to change the scale of the "Day of year" because it isn't possible to see the exactly month in the plot, for exqmple June.

Comment: I updated my response. Note that if you want to look at the difference between different websites, you'll have to include the `website` variable.

Comment: And the `yearly` plot in my original response shows the change in website traffic over each year. For example, "July 01" marks the estimated increase or decrease in traffic that is estimated to occur on July 1 of any year once you account for the overall trend and weekly effects.